How to completely change a new theme for Magento 2 without any older theme files
I am going to change a new theme for my Magento 2 store, as knowledge provided by Adobe developer that we need to clear the categories:
var/view_preprocessed,
var/cache,
var/page_cache,
pub/static,
app/code/vendor_name,
app/design/frontend/theme_name,
Are there any other categories we need to remove before uploading the new theme files?
Thank you.
